# ionic navigation animation when staying on same state

Tags: angularjs, animation, navigation, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I have an ionic app that has a detail view for displaying details for certain elements. On each detail view I display buttons to the `next` and `previous` elements. On navigation the State stays the same, only the view model instance will change and the new data will be displayed. My `state` looks like:

```
.state('main.tabs', {
  url: '/element/:id',
  params: {
    previous: null,
    next: null
  },
  cache: false,
  views: {
    'pageContent': {
      templateUrl: 'element/templates/element.tabs.html',
      controller: 'ElementTabCtrl as tabCtrl',
    }
  },
  resolve: {
    activeElement: function (DataService, $stateParams) {
      return DataService.setActiveElement($stateParams.id);
    }
  }
})
```

the function that triggers navigation is:

```
  $scope.tabNav = function (tabSref) {
    $state.go(tabSref, {id:activeElement.id});
  }
```

Now whenever I click on a button the `tabNav()` function is called, the screen freezes for some miliseconds, before the new parameters are loaded into the view.

How can I either perform navigation animations or show a loading screen that stays until the activeElement is changed?

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: Reload the view. You can add a third "options" object to the $state.go call with an attribute reload to always reload the current view which will in turn trigger a navigation animation and remove the screen freeze.

```
$state.go(tabSref, { id: activeElement.id }, { reload: true });
```

See http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state for more information.

> reload (v0.2.5) - {boolean=false|string|object}, If true will force transition even if no state or params have changed. It will reload the resolves and views of the current state and parent states. If reload is a string (or state object), the state object is fetched (by name, or object reference); and \ the transition reloads the resolves and views for that matched state, and all its children states.

Option 2: Display a loading screen. Ionic has an $ionicLoading service that you can utilize to overlay a loading screen whilst the page transitions. According to the `ui-router` wiki https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki, a `$stateChangeSuccess` event is broadcast once the transition is complete, meaning you can do the following:

```
$ionicLoading.show({ template: 'Loading...' });

$state.go(tabSref, { id: activeElement.id });

$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', _onChangeStateSuccess);

function _onChangeStateSuccess () {
  $ionicLoading.hide();
}
```

> **$stateChangeSuccess** - fired once the state transition is complete.
>      $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){ ... })

You can read more about $ionicLoading here http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicLoading/

Comment: option 1 is not working for me (because of the resolve stopping navigation maybe?) option 2 works (kind of) but its to fast so it flickers only shortly. I need some way maybe to fade the view out on navigation and fade in when the new state is loaded.

Comment: I updated my answer to demonstrate the use of ui-routers $stateChangeSuccess broadcast rather than the promise returned by $state.go. Let me know if you have better luck this way.